# Python rellenar cajas

Tags: python, bucle-for

quería saber como puedo hacer para mejorar este código en Python, hasta ahora me muestra la cantidad de "cajas" (10 de espacio cada caja) que se necesitan para guardar cada "pieza"(que ocupa espacio x cada una).
Y lo que me falta y me gustaría agregar es optimizar esto para que no me queden "espacios vacíos" en cada caja, tipo... una forma para poder optimizar los espacios remanentes

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import networkx as nx
    import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
    from plotnine import *

    piezas= [4,2,3,4,5,6,10,4,2,1,3] #cada numero es un tamaño de cada pieza
    n = len(piezas) #cantidad de piezas
    capacidad = 10 #capacidad para cada caja

    aux = 0 #variable auxiliar que nos permite contar la cantidad de cajas
    aux2 = capacidad #variable que nos va actualizando la capacidad de cada una de las cajas



    #for i in range(n):
      #remanente[i]=piezas[i]
    #print(remanente)

    for k in range(len(piezas)): #para cada pieza         
            if aux2 >= piezas[k]: #ver si la capacidad de las cajas sigue teniendo disponibilidad
                aux2 = aux2 - piezas[k] #si tiene disponibilidad se actualiza el número de la capacidad y sigue con el siguiete objeto
            else: # si no había capacidad
                aux += 1 #se crea una nueva caja
                aux2 = capacidad - piezas[k] # se guarda el objeto en esta caja
                #cajas[j] = aux 

    print(aux)
```

Comment: veamos, no estás teniendo un error, ni una duda sobre python, sino que planteas una duda de lógica en todo caso u opinión. Como no amerita una respuesta, te doy otra propuesta, sumar todos los elementos y dividirlos por la cantidad que entra en cada caja, mostrando las cajas y remanentes

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Gracias voy a replantear la lógica, dices tipo sumpiezas = sum(piezas) luego una variable que divida x = sumpiezas/10 verdad? El problema es quee son enteros y me quedaría con decimales, de verdad disculpa si es algo bobo estoy aprendiendo y me cuesta replantear otros "escenarios" con la lógica muchas gracias por responder tan rapido @tincopasan

Comment: Te contesto pero si quieres más ayuda empieza por leer todos los comentarios, entre ellos como preguntar, tu problema principal es no conocer los métodos que dispone python: cajas, quedan= divmod(sum(piezas),10); if quedan != 0:  cajas+=1;  
print(cajas), se resume solo a eso.